# Can I get index of items in gridster2 after dragging

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, angular-gridster2

```
I just want a index of items of get both source and target items :
1.drageed item
2.on which item it is dropped
```

is there any way to getting index.

I tried itemChangeCallback - it gives me 2 times which are exchange with each other but it doesn't give me the indexes of them

Answer (score 0):

Try code below :D

```
const droppedItem = document.getElementById(".dropped");
const index = items.findIndex(item => item.id === droppedItem.id);
console.log(index);
```

Comment: this is not working in angular gridster, not able to find this id.